How to know `std::vector::begin()` become invalid?
The code snippet below is seen at cppreference.
Why the std::vector::begin() is invalid when the vector is inserted the third time. I think the std::vector::begin() become invalid when the vector has been reallocated.
Does the reallocation is strictly defined in the C++ stardard? If not, it seems the std::vector::begin() should be called every time when insert() is called in the demo code.
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
 
void print(int id, const std::vector<int>& container)
{
    std::cout << id << ". ";
    for (const int x : container)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
 
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> c1(3, 100);
    print(1, c1);
 
    auto it = c1.begin();
    it = c1.insert(it, 200);
    print(2, c1);
 
    c1.insert(it, 2, 300);  //ME: why begin() still valid?
    print(3, c1);
 
    // `it` no longer valid, get a new one:
    it = c1.begin();
 
    std::vector<int> c2(2, 400);
    c1.insert(std::next(it, 2), c2.begin(), c2.end());
    print(4, c1);
 
    int arr[] = {501, 502, 503};
    c1.insert(c1.begin(), arr, arr + std::size(arr));
    print(5, c1);
 
    c1.insert(c1.end(), {601, 602, 603});
    print(6, c1);
}


"Why begin() still valid?" At that line of the code, it is no longer begin(). Its value was changed on the line it = c1.insert(it, 200); because it's the left hand side of an assignment.

it is updated after each call to insert. Perhaps you missed that it is assigned here  it = c1.insert(it, 200);  (and later it isnt updated anymore because it will not be used)

Any change of std::vector may invalidate its iterators, so removing or adding an element to the vector may invalidate begin too. So the rule is to assume std::begin is no longer valid after an insert or delete of an element. (When it actually happens depends on the actual implementation of your std::vector). So formally using vector begin() after an insertion or deletion is undefined behavior

It doesn't necessarily get a new begin(), but it gets a new valid value. However, on the line c1.insert(it, 2, 300), the value of it is not updated.

@PepijnKramer using an iterator value stored from some previous call to vector begin() after an insertion, contrasted with using the current value of vector begin()

Handy reading: Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers aggregates the rules for all of the Standard containers into one easy-to-find document broken down by Standard revision.

Iterator invalidation .

The example shows you not to store iterators for later use. Iterators are supposed to be instantly consumed after construction. So, their only valid use cases is function argument and return.

The C++ standard gives std library latitude on when it invalidates vectors.
It places requirements, but does not mandate implementation.  These requirements mean that a family of implementations are possible.  The actual implementations have guided the standard text, and the standard text has in turn guided the implementations.
Most languages that are not C++ have one implementation.  So the standard for that language describes what the implementation does.  In C++ land this doesn't happen, so things are a layer more abstract.
I will now give a description of how, in practice, C++ std implementers do.  It will contain a few "lies told to children" to keep it simple.
The std::vector<T> manages a buffer of memory, some of which contains objects of type T, plus a count of how many objects are in that buffer.
When you do an operation whose resulting vector fits within that buffer, the std::vector<T> just uses that buffer.
So, for example, a given vector might have a buffer with room for 7 Ts, and have only 3 in use.  If you add an element, it would shuffle the elements around and wouldn't reallocate anything.
However, if you added 5 elements, that would no longer fit in your buffer (as 3+5=8, which is greater than 7).  At this point the std::vector<T> triggers a reallocation.
When a reallocation occurs -- when the buffer gets replaced with a larger one - all iterators are invalidated.
If you do a .reserve() to a larger size, std::vector implementations tend to grow the vector to exactly the size you ask.  But if you do .push_back or .insert or similar operations, the std::vector implementations are required to pull off something called "amortized constant cost".  In effect, this means they have to grow in size exponentially.
If you start with a vector with a buffer with room for 1 element, and you keep pushing back, the buffer doesn't grow like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...".  Instead, it grows like "1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 17, 26, ..." or "1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...".  Some function that behaves asymptotically like "k^n".
Two typical growth rates are "twice the old buffer size" and "1.5 times the old buffer size"; different implementations pick different growth rates, and the C++ standard is flexible enough to allow either.  (there are advantages to faster or slower growth rates).
Because of that flexibility in how fast the implementation chooses to grow, the standard doesn't say when iterators are invalidated for a given program.  It just says under what conditions they can be invalidated.
A std::vector iterator can be invalidated whenever .capacity() changes.  .reserve() guarantees a minimum .capacity().  .size() is always less than or equal to .capacity().  .insert() and .push_* methods can all grow .size().
So a first tier safety thing is to not assume iterators remain valid if you are adding elements to the vector.  This rule is strong enough.
Sometimes you want to get fancy.  If you want to get fancy, you have to at run time get .capacity() when you get your iterators, and ensure your set of operations adding elements never passes that valid.  If so, you can guarantee your iterators won't be invalidated by adding elements.
(The other common way vector iterators are invalidated is swap, move-assignment and move-construction from or two a vector.  In the case of move-construction and swap, the iterators are defined to migrate to the other container; in the case of move-assignment, no such guarantee is provided, as it leaves it up to the implementation to decide on a runtime basis if the vector should move elements or move buffers)

I think the biggest lie is "count of valid elements"; often it is 3 pointers (buffer start, one past buffer end, one past last valid element".  The count being (last valid)-(buffer start), which isn't (always? usually?) actually explicitly stored.

one past buffer end, one past last valid element. What are they?

close to the end "...and ensure your set of operations adding elements never passes that valid."  ? never passes that limit?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai They never called "capacity" in your example code, so I have no idea why you think you never passed it.

@John They are values I described.  That comment is an attempt to give implementation details that are explicitly not "lies told to children", it is not an attempt to be easily understood.  I am saying what (if you actually look at the implementation) is stored.  The "lies told to children" are meant to be understood.  If your question is "what is that", please see the "lies told to children"

sry I dont understand your reply. My comment was refering to your sentence which either I misunderstand completely or is missing a word or is unclear.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah.  "that" here is a reference to an earlier subject, in this case .capacity(), in the same sentence.  The missing word was part of the "..." you removed from the sentence.  "... and ensure (your set of operations adding elements never passes .capacity()) valid".  Maybe I need an "is"?


Why the std::vector::begin() is invalid when the vecotr is inserted the third time.

I suppose it's a nitpick on wording, but details matter, so: std::vector::begin() is not invalid. It always returns a valid iterator. Only when the vector is empty then std::vector::begin() == std::vector::end(). Though, a previously stored iterator may get invalidated any time insert is called.

Does the reallocation is strictly defined in the C++ stardard?

No. It is an implementation detail. Though, the way the C++ standard specifies std::vector, it is clear that reallocation has to happen (and of course the specification was written with that in mind). And the requirements on time complexity of inserting elements is such that an implementation cannot reallocate on every single insertion. Hence, every insertion potentially invalidates iterators.

std::vector::begin() should be called every time when insert() is called in the demo code.

No. it is used several times in the code. Always when an element is inserted, the iterator it is updated with a valid iterator before it is used again.


Does the reallocation is strictly defined in the C++ stardard?

It is defined that std::vector is allowed to reallocate, but not when. You simply can call reserve or resize before adding new data. Often the algo is to duplicate the allocated memory if new data needs reallocation, means 2,4,8,16...
You simply can take a look at std::vector in the section Iterator invalidation to get an idea when iterators will be invalidated.
